# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'edycja' Django

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem. I've create a app where I can added the new records and edit. And now in edit this problem appear. When I select from list the record to edit -> form loading me properly the filled fields with datas. But when I click on Edit button to update the datas, the Django return me a error:

```
**invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'edycja'**
```

I don't know exacly where is a problem. Maybe somebody could help me?
Here is the part of my **views.py**

```
@login_required
def szczegoly_pracownik(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/szczegoly_pracownik.html', {'link_pracownik': link_pracownik})

@login_required
def edycja_pracownika(request, id):
    link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.POST, instance=link_pracownik)
        if edycja_pracownika.is_valid():
            link_pracownik = edycja_pracownika.save(commit=False)
            link_pracownik.save()
            return render('szczegoly_pracownik', id=link_pracownik.id)
    else:
        edycja_pracownika = CudzoziemiecForm(request.user, instance=link_pracownik)
    return render(request, 'cudzoziemiec/edycja_pracownika.html', {'edycja_pracownika': edycja_pracownika})
```

And when I read the log the error is somewhere in **def szczegoly_pracownik**

EDIT:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/konto/pracownik/edycja/

Django Version: 2.0.1
Python Version: 3.6.3
Installed Applications:
['cudzoziemiec',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Django\zatrudnienie\cudzoziemiec\views.py" in szczegoly_pracownik
  77.   link_pracownik = get_object_or_404(Cudzoziemiec, id=id)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in get_object_or_404
  87.         return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in get
  394.         clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  836.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  854.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1253.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1277.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1215.         condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_lookup
  1085.         lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in __init__
  18.         self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py" in get_prep_lookup
  68.             return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)

File "D:\Django\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py" in get_prep_value
  947.         return int(value)

Exception Type: ValueError at /konto/pracownik/edycja/
Exception Value: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'edycja'
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback from the log? It should help identify better where the issue occurs

Comment: mxbi I've edit my question

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? You're passing the string 'edycja' in the URL and using it to try and look up by ID. Why? What does that string represent?

Comment: look:  Request URL: http://localhost:8000/konto/pracownik/edycja/

the ID should be integer

Comment: Ok I've delete the 'edycja' from url and the error dissapear. But I don't know why the edit do not saving the changes....